# How to trigger flask API on a particular date or time?

Tags: python, api, flask

How can i trigger an API on 09th of every month.

```
import os
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify

@data_engine_app.route('/api/update/time', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return 'Updated on time'
```

Comment: create a request or scheduler which will send request to your Api on 9th of every month

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OS utilities to run a script on specific time. eg, scheduled job on Windows.

If you want to do using python, you can try [these](https://medium.com/greedygame-engineering/an-elegant-way-to-run-periodic-tasks-in-python-61b7c477b679).